# RE: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Keeps Crashing Looking for help with error log

Tags: 20.04, crash, log

Ubuntu 20.04.01 keeps crashing.

The following is the error log of the last boot before crash using: `journalctl -b -1 -e`

```
Dec 09 10:40:12 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS
Dec 09 10:40:12 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 reason=4 locally_generated=1
Dec 09 10:40:12 tizzy NetworkManager[1040]: <warn>  [1607503212.9972] sup-iface[0x557e63aafb00,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Dec 09 10:40:12 tizzy kernel: rtw_pci 0000:04:00.0: sta ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 with macid 0 left
Dec 09 10:40:13 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Dec 09 10:40:13 tizzy NetworkManager[1040]: <info>  [1607503213.0345] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Dec 09 10:40:13 tizzy NetworkManager[1040]: <info>  [1607503213.2484] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Dec 09 10:40:13 tizzy gnome-shell[34247]: [34233:34399:1209/104013.390103:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(428)] Failed to connect to MCS e>
Dec 09 10:40:13 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Dec 09 10:40:14 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Dec 09 10:40:14 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Dec 09 10:40:16 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 (SSID='Pixel_6597' freq=2462 MHz)
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy kernel: wlo1: authenticate with ae:e0:8b:35:17:78
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy NetworkManager[1040]: <info>  [1607503217.2202] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy kernel: wlo1: send auth to ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 (try 1/3)
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy kernel: wlo1: send auth to ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 (try 2/3)
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: Trying to associate with ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 (SSID='Pixel_6597' freq=2462 MHz)
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy kernel: wlo1: authenticated
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy kernel: wlo1: associate with ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 (try 1/3)
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy NetworkManager[1040]: <info>  [1607503217.3356] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associat>
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=4)
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy kernel: rtw_pci 0000:04:00.0: sta ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 joined with macid 0
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy kernel: wlo1: associated
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: Associated with ae:e0:8b:35:17:78
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy NetworkManager[1040]: <info>  [1607503217.3533] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy gnome-shell[33209]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy gnome-shell[33209]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy gnome-shell[33209]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy NetworkManager[1040]: <info>  [1607503217.3638] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handsh>
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to ae:e0:8b:35:17:78 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy NetworkManager[1040]: <info>  [1607503217.3710] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> complet>
Dec 09 10:40:17 tizzy wpa_supplicant[1077]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-17 noise=9999 txrate=65000
Dec 09 10:40:18 tizzy systemd-resolved[989]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.56.137.
```